# How do I encrypt these cryptographic keys properly?

Tags: rust, cryptography

**Description:** I am working on a cryptography project and I want to encrypt both the public key and the private key, but the function that lets me do this only accepts strings and bytes, not tuples or anything else, and I want to be able to pass both keys into there at once and get it to encrypt, which I can't seem to do. I've tried using tuples and vecs but I don't think you can turn these into bytes.

**Goal:** Be able to pass both the public and private keys at the same time and get it to encrypt successfully.

Dependencies: `pqcrypto-dilithium = "0.4.5"` and `magic-crypt = "3.1.10"`. Import this in Cargo.toml

Import:

```
pub use pqcrypto_dilithium::dilithium5::*;
pub use pqcrypto_dilithium::dilithium5::DetachedSignature;
pub use magic_crypt::{new_magic_crypt, MagicCryptTrait, MagicCryptError};
```

Code:

```
pub fn magic_encrypt(phrase: &String, public_key: &pqcrypto_dilithium::dilithium5::PublicKey, 
    private_key: &pqcrypto_dilithium::dilithium5::SecretKey) -> (String, String, String) {
    let salt = "salt";
    let phrase_and_salt = phrase.to_owned() + &salt;
    return (new_magic_crypt!(&phrase_and_salt, 256).encrypt_bytes_to_base64(***),
    hash_string(&phrase_and_salt), salt);
}
```

How can I do this? Without modifying the source files of course.

Comment: You probably want to serialize your data, then encrypt it. Rust has very good serialization support with serde.

Comment: So here's the problem now, how do I serialize data structures that aren't within my crate. Like structs from imported modules?

Comment: Some crates have a `serde` flag or just just directly implement the required traits. Otherwise, you have to do something a little more convoluted explained at https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html.

Comment: The `pqcrypto_dilithium` crate does not seem to implement `(De)Serialize` for their key types. However, both public and secret key have an `.as_bytes()` and `.from_bytes()` method that you can use for (de)serialization

Comment: @msrd0 I know that but I need to encrypt them together, at the same time. This won't work for that.

Comment: Why would you encrypt a *public* key? Here is google.com public key: `04 54 AA 50 BC 50 2F BE ED DC EC 01 1F 82 7A 51 E1 D2 19 9D 32 50 D5 44 78 5B 17 C4 8D 60 29 B4 0C 36 82 F1 6A CD DD 14 D5 76 D4 63 73 EA 63 0F 04 76 8B E5 FE CB CD 0D 0B B7 03 24 27 30 67 08 8D`. Encrypt the private key using `as_bytes`.

Comment: Genius comment @ixe013. Thanks. That never came up in my head.

Comment: If you still need the public key encrypted as well, you could use both `as_bytes()` methods and then use serde to serialize the `(&[u8], &[u8])` tuple into a single byte array.